# PS script that monitors folder and copies to new folder and renames

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to fix a PowerShell script that I have and add some more features to it. Currently, it's working as intended: when a file is saved to a directory, it moves the item to a new one.

What I'm looking to add to it is instead of just overwriting the existing file, it renames it to `yyyyMMdd`. The files are all the same and are always the same name/extension, so adding this would be a great way for some semi version control.

```
$folder = 'C:\scripts\test'
$filter = '*.*'                             # <-- set this according to your requirements
$destination = 'H:\Office Documents\text_move'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true              # <-- set this according to your requirements
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
 $dirname = [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($folder)
 $filename=[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
 $ext = [io.path]::GetExtension($file)
 $newpath = "$destination\$filename\$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd)$ext"
 Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -verbose

}
```

I get that I need to add to string the `get-date`, but I can't seem for the life of me figure out how or where to add that in to make it work the way I think it should.

Comment: Howdy! Ss far all you've done is tell us what you want and give us the script you have that doesn't do it.  We are not a script writing service, but can/will help with specific scripting problem you run into.  Please edit your question to include answer to: What have you attempted already? What were the results? Where exactly are you getting stuck implementing this new feature?   Otherwise this may/will be closed as too broad.

Comment: My mistake, I did update one of the things I tried. I've tried lots of other ways but I either A: break everything or B: it just seems to go over it and it still overwrites it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$folder = 'C:\scripts\test'
$filter = '*.*'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
IncludeSubdirectories = $true
NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
# define the destination inside this script block
$destination = 'H:\Office Documents\text_move'

$createdFile = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$createdFileName = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$createdFileTimeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

Write-Output "Trigger: Get-Date -Format 'u'" >> c:\scripts\logWatcher.txt

$existingFileName = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $createdFileName
if(Test-Path($existingFileName)) {
Write-Output "File: '$createdFileName' exists at: $destination - renaming existing file first" >> c:\scripts\logWatcher.txt
$newFileName = "$(get-date -Format 'yyyyMMdd')$createdFileName"
Rename-Item -Path $existingFileName -NewName $newFileName
}

Move-Item $createdFile -Destination $existingFileName -verbose
Write-Output "File: '$createdFileName' State: $changeType At: $createdFileTimeStamp" >> c:\scripts\logWatcher.txt
Start-Process https://website.blah/app.jnlp

}
$onCreated
```

This is what I ended up using to make it work. I had lots of variable errors as well as lots of issues with where I needed certain things. I had help writing it as well as suggestions. The watcher log helped a lot because it gave me a point of reference to what I was doing and what was happening.

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -noexit -file "c:\scripts\move-filefinal.ps1"
```

In a batch file allows me to have it running non-stop in the background, if anyone has a better suggestion to that, I'm all ears.

Thanks for the help and pushing me in the right direction though, I think this was way harder than it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this logic to set the name of the file

```
$dirName  = [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($folder)
$filename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
$ext      = [io.path]::GetExtension($file)
$newPath  = "$destination\$filename $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)$ext"
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954203/powershell-timestamp-on-file-name)

Comment: Playing around with what you wrote, its now adding a new file instead of overwriting the old one, so in an instance, I would just get New Microsoft Word Document, I'm now getting New Microsoft Word Document (2).docx

Certainly a step in the right direction as before it would just overwrite.